# Grails doesn't save when using findAll but does when using collection

Tags: session, grails, collections, grails-orm, data-persistence

I have this code:

```
void updateIndex() {
    Visit.withNewSession {
        def results = patient.visits.sort{ it.date }

        results.eachWithIndex { item, index ->
            item.index = index
        }
    }
}
```

This saves to the DB without a save(). I changed the results to use a findAll query (because I only wanted a selection of them) and now it doesn't save the changes to the DB. I do see the changes to the indices but these changes never get persisted.

```
def results = Visit.findAllByPatientAndTypeInList(
                this.patient,
                [Type.Test, Type.Junk]
            ).sort{ it.date }
```

Is this one of those GORM gotcha's? I tried to explicit call a save (and check for any errors) and still no luck.

Comment: Can you try with save(flush:true, failOnError:true) and see if there is any exception?

Comment: The sort() method modifies the original collection. In your case, patient.visits. That collection is attached to the Hibernate session, so it knows what it has changed. The collection returned by the dynamic finder is different. It's doesn't watch for changes you make. What happens when you use toSorted() instead of sort() in your first example?

Comment: @LalitAgarwal I tried the save() but sometimes I get: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect).

Answer (score 3):

Those are 2 different pairs of shoes.

In the 1st case you were sorting a list of `hasMany` objects, which are linked to the `patient` via a join-table with an `list index` field. So when you sort the list, the join-table's index field gets dirty and will be updated upon tx-commit.

In the 2nd case, you get a list of instances but no `list index` info. So, whatever you do to the list - re-ordering, adding or removing its entries - does NOT make it's instances `dirty`. Ergo, they are not saved even upon `save()`

Comment: So how do I save those changes?

Comment: what changes do you want to save?